# Listening to realtime update in Firestore from ios using swift 4

Tags: ios, xcode, google-cloud-firestore, swift4

I'm trying to listen to creation of a specific document in a collection and then print the document data once change has occurred. This listening should stop only if app is closed or document has been created.

I tried to use code from the document but by experience found that even if the document doesn't exist, listening gets stopped after one execution with the print statement - "Document data was empty."

```
        let uid = "DocumentID"
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("MyCollection").document(uid!)
        .addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
            guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
                print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            guard let data = document.data() else {
                print("Document data was empty.")
                return
            }
            let data = document.data()
            print("Current data: \(String(describing: data))")
```

I need the code which can wait till document is created in a collection and then print the data in it where document id is previously known.

Comment: Hi @ManishWalter, I think you can create field on `Realtime Database` and listen your Firestore changes, when document added you can trigger your code and start listrn with `Firestore.firestore()`

Comment: Can't we listen directly just like we do in android